# How do I resolve this pcre3 error while installing lede-mptcp?

Tags: pcre

https://spyff.github.io/mptcp/2017/08/27/transparent-mptcp-proxy/
I am following the steps as mentioned in above link to install lede-mptcp in my ubuntu virtual machine while doing "make" I am getting the following errors.

```
checking for pcre headers in ... not found
checking for library containing pcre_exec... no
configure: error: Cannot find pcre library. Configure --with-pcre=DIR
Makefile:132: recipe for target '/home/phani/lede-mptcp/build_dir/target-x86_64_musl-1.1.16/shadowsocks-libev-3.3.5/.configured_08bfbcccd69d96242ca8a0162f4ebe27' failed
make[3]: *** [/home/phani/lede-mptcp/build_dir/target-x86_64_musl-1.1.16/shadowsocks-libev-3.3.5/.configured_08bfbcccd69d96242ca8a0162f4ebe27] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/phani/lede-mptcp/feeds/packages/net/shadowsocks-libev'
package/Makefile:105: recipe for target 'package/feeds/packages/shadowsocks-libev/compile' failed
make[2]: *** [package/feeds/packages/shadowsocks-libev/compile] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/phani/lede-mptcp'
package/Makefile:101: recipe for target '/home/phani/lede-mptcp/staging_dir/target-x86_64_musl-1.1.16/stamp/.package_compile' failed
make[1]: *** [/home/phani/lede-mptcp/staging_dir/target-x86_64_musl-1.1.16/stamp/.package_compile] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/phani/lede-mptcp'
/home/phani/lede-mptcp/include/toplevel.mk:205: recipe for target 'world' failed
make: *** [world] Error 2
```

I tried to solve the error by installing libpcre3 and libpcre3-dev but not solved yet.

Please,Let me know the solution if anyone faced same issue and have solution.

Thanks & Regards,
Phani Sree.